# Firefox 3.6 update breaks selenium

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium

I'm unable to run any selenium tests since I updated Firefox to 3.6. Is it happening just to me or is it everybody?

Error message I get is: `Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start browser session`

This is in Windows Xp.

Comment: It happened to me too. I ended up downgrading FireFox to 3.5.7
Fortunately, it was easy to do: http://computersservicing.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-downgrade-from-firefox-36-to.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Found the problem. My Netbeans was using version 1.0.1 which did not support 3.6.

This fixed it: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924105617/http://geekswithblogs.net/thomasweller/archive/2010/02/14/making-selenium-1.0.1-work-with-firefox-3.6.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the extension "Nightly Test Tool" before a extension officially supports a new released version.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 1.0.3 was updated to work with Firefox 3.6 so suggest updating your version instead of going in and hacking the jar file.

You can get the latest version from http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list

Comment: I was using the Selenium Plugin for Netbeans. Tried that, but looks like replacing the Netbeans jar file breaks the plugin..